# Running `TestRig` on separated grammer and lexer results in `java.lang.ClassCastException` or `Can't load Test as lexer or parser`

Tags: java, antlr

I have a separated parser and lexer grammar and want to run `org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig` to debug/test my grammar.

My lexer grammar start with:

```
lexer grammar TestLexer;

IDS: [a-zA-Z];

WS: [ \t];
NL: [\r?\n];

...
```

and my parser grammar start with:

```
parser grammar TestParser;
options { tokenVocab=TestLexer; }

testRule: WS* IDS+ NL;

...
```

My classpath env variable points to complete `antlr.jar` and current directory.

- `antlr` is an alias to `java org.antlr.v4.Tool`
- `grun` is an alias to `java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig`.

When I run `antlr TestParser.g4 && javac *.java` the parser code gets generated and compiled.

When I run `grun TestParser testRule -gui` I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class TestParser
        at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:3404)
        at org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig.process(TestRig.java:135)
        at org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig.main(TestRig.java:119)
```

And when I run `grun Test testRule -gui` I get the error:

```
Can't load Test as lexer or parser
```

I don't have any problems when using a combined grammar.

What's missing in order to run `TestRig`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using separated lexer and parser you have to generate the code for the lexer and parser. This is not done automatically by generating the code for the parser alone.

Execute:

```
antlr TestLexer.g4
antlr TestParser.g4
javac *.java
```

After generating the code for both (lexer and parser) you have to run:

```
grun Test -gui testInput.txt
```

where `testInput.txt` contains some test input to parse.

**Note:** When using separated lexer and parser it's expected that the lexer ends on `Lexer` and the parser ends on `Parser`. The common part of the files is the name of grammar. 
I.e `TestLexer` and `TestParser` -> `Test` is the name of the grammar.